# Why does this class method generate a TypeError?

Tags: python, class, sequence

I am writing a class to create a mathematical sequence, however, when I call the class methods `getValueRange` or `getValueList`, I get a TypeError for, seemingly, appending to the `nums` list.

Here is the class definition:

```
class Sequence:
    def __init__(self, term: str, var: str):
        self.term = term
        self.var = var

    def getValueAt(self, pos: int) -> int:
        return int(eval(self.term.replace(self.var, str(pos))))

    def getValueRange(self, pos1: int, pos2: int) -> list:
        nums = []

        for i in range(pos1, pos2):
            nums += self.getValueAt(i)

        return nums

    def getValueList(self, pos_list: list):
        nums = []

        for i in pos_list:
            nums += self.getValueAt(int(i))

        return nums


sq = Sequence("5*x-6", "x")
print(sq.getValueAt(1))
print(sq.getValueAt(2))
print(sq.getValueRange(4, 44))
print(sq.getValueList([5, 9, 27]))
```

Here is my error:

```
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\PycharmProjects\Wistfully\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(sq.getValueRange(4, 44))
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\PycharmProjects\Wistfully\main.py", line 13, in getValueRange
    nums += self.getValueAt(i)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I have tried commenting out the appending to nums list in both functions and just printed out the results, which worked perfectly. I debugged all variables, and I am most definitely missing something.

Comment: `list += int` does not append to the `list`. It raises a `TypeError`. To append use `list.append(int)` or `nums.append(self.getValueAt(i))`.

Comment: As an aside, in Python terminology, these are "instance methods", not "class methods"

Answer (score 2):

You wrote (roughly) this:

```
        nums = []
        ...
            nums += 7
```

That won't work, as the integer `7` is not an iterable container.

You *could* use `nums += str(...)`, but for multi-digit results
that's probably not what you want.

Better to just

```
            nums.append(7)
```

Or append that `getValueAt` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Change `nums += self.getValueAt(int(i))` to `nums.append(self.getValueAt(int(i)))`. Using `+=` to append items to lists only works if the items you're appending are in a list (edit: or another kind of iterable).

Comment: "_only works if the items you're appending are in a list_" Not true. works for any iterable.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Thanks. Also I would've been fine if you'd just edited my answer to reflect that, but I went ahead and did it.